# parray stopped working in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have changed the TCL inbuilt `unknown` procedure. I have *renamed the `unknown` to `_unknown`* and and do some custom checks in new unknown procedure. Problem is it stopped parray comamnd. when i set an array and then do parray it prints the message `invalid command name "parray abc"`

Below is the code

```
rename unknown _unknown
proc unknown args {
    puts "inside unknwn proc"
    if { ![regexp {65ABC::\w+\s.*} $args] } {
        uplevel 1 [list _unknown $args]
    } else {
        regexp {(65SABC::\w+)\s+(.*)} $args - procName params
        regsub {65ABC::} $procName "65ABC8X::" procName
        eval "$procName $params"
    }
}

set abc(1) one
parray abc

inside unknwn proc
invalid command name "parray abc"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your code... I get `parray` to work just fine even after renaming `unknown`.

Comment: have u launched new shell or pasted the code in same shell

Comment: Can't reproduce the error either. I think something else must be wrong in your code.

Comment: @Nitesh I copy/pasted the whole code in a new shell.

Comment: I pasted the code in codepad.org and got the same error

Comment: @Hoodiecrow: Code pasted above is giving error. There is nothing other than that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
uplevel 1 [list _unknown $args]
```

As that forces the whole list of arguments to be interpreted as a single argument. Hence the weird command name.
To be exact, the problem was that you were ending up calling something equivalent to `uplevel 1 {_unknown {parray abc}}` instead of `uplevel 1 {_unknown parray abc}` (which is what you really wanted to call). Tcl's usually very exact about word boundaries and error messages; they tell you precisely what is wrong if you read them carefully.

It should be *one* of these:

```
uplevel 1 [list _unknown {*}$args]
```

```
uplevel 1 _unknown $args
```

Prefer the first if you're using 8.5 or 8.6; use the second on 8.4 (or earlier).

Comment: This is working. I have used the second options. It would be great if you let me know why the solution is working

Comment: And why are we not getting this error? Why is `unknown` being invoked in the first place?

Comment: @Nitesh Sorry for the short answer before; I was just heading into a meeting here. ;-)

Comment: @Hoodiecrow Did you run `parray` before testing? That would have autoloaded the `parray` implementation, so invoking it wouldn't have gone via `unknown` (the standard implementation of which contains the call to the autoloader, among many other things).

Comment: Yes, when I look at people's problems I usually run through the code that _should_ work first for comparison and then try to introduce the problem and try again. Now that method doesn't seem optimal anymore. At all. At least I should run the "good code" and the "bad code" in different, newly started interpreters. (This is kind of a note-to-self.)